# Do you really use the word "google" as a verb?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, verbing

Do you really use the word "google" as a verb?

If so, how often? always? or you use other verb such as "search" more than "google"?

Comment: It's an example of a trademark which has come to be used as a general term for things of that kind - see list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_generic_and_genericized_trademarks) . Some of them have become verbs, such as _hoover up_ (suck up with, or like, a vacuum cleaner).

Comment: "And all this time I thought Googling yourself meant the other thing!" ~ Marge Simpson.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "google" is commonly used as a verb, meaning "looked up/searched online." I personally use "google" much more frequently than I say "I searched."

> I wondered how old Roger Federer is, so I googled it.
>
> Do you know a good recipe for chocolate cake? - Just google for one.
>
> I need to get more comfortable with spreadsheets, so I googled some basic Excel tips.

Comment: I'd capitalise 'Google' when using it as a verb. "Google
takes initial cap, even when used as a verb (“I Googled myself”); " - [Guardian style guide](https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-g)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Other outlets have different style guides. It's in use both ways, and particularly where it's more loosely used to mean 'look it up' regardless of which search engine is used, the lower case is appropriate.